# How to connect the QuaZip library in CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, quazip

My project uses the QuaZip library, and I need to build the project through CMake. How to add this library to CMakeLists? 
From the library I need JlCompress

My CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
#set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
#set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY PREDEFINED_TARGETS_FOLDER "cmake")

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)

project(Archiver LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Widgets Gui)
find_package(zlib)
find_package(QuaZip5)
include_directories(${QUAZIP_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(project_ui
    mainwindow.ui)
set(project_headers
    archive.h
    mainwindow.h)
set(project_sources
    main.cpp
    archive.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp)

qt5_wrap_ui(project_headers_wrapped ${project_ui})
qt5_wrap_cpp(project_sources_moc ${project_headers})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${project_headers} ${project_sources} 
    ${project_sources_moc} ${project_headers_wrapped})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    PUBLIC 
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Gui
    Qt5::Widgets
    ${QUAZIP_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Build error:

> CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package):   By not providing
>   "Findquazip.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has   asked CMake
>   to find a package configuration file provided by "quazip", but   CMake
>   did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "quazip"
>   with any   of the following names:
>
> ```
> quazipConfig.cmake
> quazip-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "quazip" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set 
>   "quazip_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
>   "quazip"   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
>   has been   installed.
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:37 (target_link_libraries):   The
>   keyword signature for target_link_libraries has already been used with
>   the target "Archiver".  All uses of target_link_libraries with a
>   target   must be either all-keyword or all-plain.
>
> The uses of the keyword signature are here:
>
> - CMakeLists.txt:31 (target_link_libraries)

Comment: Post some code what have you tried

Comment: Ok, I laid out all my CMakeLists

Comment: You show the code which uses `quazip`, what is a **problem** with it? If it produces an error, then add this error into the question post.

Comment: Ok. I added it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find script for quazip is named [FindQuaZip5.cmake](https://github.com/stachenov/quazip/blob/master/FindQuaZip.cmake) (it is renamed during installation). So for find `quazip` you need to use

```
find_package(QuaZip5)
```

Meaning of the find script is described in its head:

```
# QUAZIP_FOUND               - QuaZip library was found
# QUAZIP_INCLUDE_DIR         - Path to QuaZip include dir
# QUAZIP_INCLUDE_DIRS        - Path to QuaZip and zlib include dir (combined from QUAZIP_INCLUDE_DIR + ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
# QUAZIP_LIBRARIES           - List of QuaZip libraries
# QUAZIP_ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR    - The include dir of zlib headers
```

That is, for use `quazip` with `zlib` in your code, add these lines:

```
include_directories(${QUAZIP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${QUAZIP_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me, please, how to include JlCompress in my project?

Comment: What is wrong with `#include <JlCompress.h>`, as shown [there](http://quazip.sourceforge.net/classJlCompress.html)?

Comment: Exception, that "No such file or directory"

Comment: Strange. What content of `QUAZIP_INCLUDE_DIRS` is? (You may print the variable's value with `message("${QUAZIP_INCLUDE_DIRS}")`. Check that one of the directories, listed in that variable, contains `JlCompress.h` file.

Comment: I wrote D:\quazip-0.7.3\quazip

Comment: "I wrote D:\quazip-0.7.3\quazip" - What does it mean in the context of my previous comment?

Comment: I have corrected to `${QUAZIP_LIBRARIES}`, but now my project found `<JlCompress.h> , but when I was building, my project had a lot of exceptions, but when I was building with qMake, I didn't have exceptions