# Build c++ Qt CLI Tool with Quazip

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, quazip, libz

so normally I am an embedded software developer first time I need to do something like that... So I am no expert at all at this... I have come this far with a lot of googling and trial and error methods...

### What I want to do

I need to write a C++ CLI application which can zip and unzip files.

- [Quazip](https://github.com/stachenov/quazip)
- [zlib](https://zlib.net/)

### My general conditions

I want to use Qt and Quazip since Qt doesn't support zipping natively (or does it).
I want to build with Mingw and CMake for Windows 64bit on a Windows 64bit system.

With my knowledge, it would be best if I compile Quazip statically so I don't depend on any other quazip DLL which may be present on other systems...

### How I think It works

1. I need to compile zlib
2. Then I need to compile Quazip (with zlib)
3. Link the compiled libraries to my project.

### My research

I found two good youtube videos which should help me:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZTusMX-Reo
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxlcKmvMK9Q

No of these ways did work out for me.
Also I found that blog post which was a little bit of help...

http://www.antonioborondo.com/2014/10/22/zipping-and-unzipping-files-with-qt/

This site was available till yesterday now it's gone :D

Also I found that old Stackoverflow question which helped me a bit:

[How to connect the QuaZip library in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223593/how-to-connect-the-quazip-library-in-cmake)

### Detailed steps on what I did:

**1. Building zlib**

Downloaded the latest version of zlib from the official website. version 1.2.11
I build zlib with the following commands:

```
cd C:/some/Path/zlib-1.2.11
mingw32-make -f win32/Makefile.gcc
```

That works perfectly I get a

- libz.a
- libz.dll.a
- zlib1.dll

those files and all the header files (11 files) I copy in a seperate folder. Which looks like this:

```
Build
|
+-include
+-lib
```

Headers in the include folder the libs in the lib folder.

**2. Building Quazip**

Now the messy part...

Downloading the newest version of Quazip (version 0.8.1) from the [GitHub](https://github.com/stachenov/quazip).

I tried various ways to compile Quazip. The one I stick to was:
Open the .pro file in Qt creator inside the quazip folder (the folder where the sources are located).

So then I added the compiled zlib to the Qmake file.
Following lines I added at the end of the file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Build/include" 
LIBS += -L"C:/Build/lib" 
LIBS += -lz
```

Then build Quazip with QtCreator as release Build.
When compiled I get

- quazip.dll
- libquazip.a

I copy all the header files from quazip (16 fils) in the include folder and the two libs in the lib folder.

Now I have like a zippackage in the build folder.

**3. Adding Quazip and zlib to my Project**

Copied the FindQuazip.cmake file into my project form the Quazip Repo.
In my CMakeLists.txt I added the following lines:

```
set(ZLIB_ROOT "C:/BUILD" CACHE PATH "Path to zlib")
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(QuaZip REQUIRED)
```

I need to set the ZLIB_ROOT so CMake uses the zlib I want. If I don't set Root he uses a zlib from a ruby installation from my PC.
Also I added

```
include_directories(
    "${BASE_DIR}/sources"
    "${QUAZIP_INCLUDE_DIR}"
    )
```

and at the end

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${INC_ALL} )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Network Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets
    ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES}
    ${QUAZIP_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

Then I needed to add the FindQuazip.cmake since it would find the libs: I edited the following:

```
FIND_PATH(QUAZIP_LIBRARY_DIR
          WIN32_DEBUG_POSTFIX d
          NAMES libquazip.a #quazip.dll
          HINTS "C:/Build/lib"
          PATH_SUFFIXES QuaZip/lib
          )
FIND_LIBRARY(QUAZIP_LIBRARIES NAMES libquazip.a HINTS ${QUAZIP_LIBRARY_DIR})
FIND_PATH(QUAZIP_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES quazip.h HINTS ${QUAZIP_LIBRARY_DIR}/../include)
FIND_PATH(QUAZIP_ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES zlib.h)
```

Okay so It took me two days to get to there where I am now. 
Now when I run CMake every works fine. He finds the libs.
I can even include a the Header files of Quazip. But when I then try to compile a minimal example the linker can't find any symbols.
Minimal Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include "JlCompress.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    cout << __cplusplus << endl;
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    JlCompress::compressDir("C:/WorkspaceLokal/Test/test.zip", "C:/WorkspaceLokal/Test/TestFolder");
    return a.exec();
}
```

By compiling it I get the following error:

> C:\some\path\sources\main.cpp:-1: Fehler: undefined reference to `JlCompress::compressDir(QString, QString, bool)'

This means the linker can't link the function...

### My Question

What am I doing wrong?
Do I need to compile Quazip in another way?

**Edit 4:**

since it now works how to I compile the Quazip as a static lib, so that I can link it statically to my application?

Thanks in advance...

**Edit 1:**

Here are the QUAZIP variables from Qt creator:
[image: Qauzip]

**Edit 2:**

Okay. Some news. the libquazip.a is something else and doesn't work. If I link against the quazip.dll compiling works. But when I run the application it crashes at the function call compressDir...

**Edit 3:**

It works. I just needed to copy the quazip.dll to the compiled executable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From QuaZip's pro file:

```
# You'll need to define this one manually if using a build system other  
# than qmake or using QuaZIP sources directly in your project.  
CONFIG(staticlib): DEFINES += QUAZIP_STATIC
```

This should trigger when you add `staticlib` to the `CONFIG` in quazip.pro (2nd line):

```
CONFIG += qt warn_on staticlib
```

If you are not using qmake to build Quazip, just make sure that you `#define QUAZIP_STATIC` in a way specific to your build system

Comment: Figured that out too. Build that and replaced  `quazip.dll` with `libquazip.a` in the FindQuaZip.cmake. Now I get a undefined reference to __imp__ZN10JlCompress11compressDirE7QStringS0_b . Any Idea?

Comment: I'm using QuaZip 0.7.1 and MSVC in my project... I get a `quazip.lib` file when defining staticlib. It is significantly larger then the old lib file and dll combined (659kB instead of 223kB). Did you re-run qmake before building? (in Qt Creator Build > Run qmake) Did you clear the output path?

Comment: From your application .pro file, you should add : DEFINES += QUAZIP_STATIC. This define will disable some import/export definitions in quazip files header.